# Adding stat = count on top of histogram in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, geom-histogram

I've seen some other examples (especially using geom_col() and stat_bin()) to add frequency or count numbers on top of bars. I'm trying to get this to work with geom_histogram() where I have a discrete (string), not continuous, x variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- cars |> 
  mutate( discrete_var = factor(speed))

ggplot(d, aes(x = discrete_var)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom='text', color='white', aes(label=..count..),
           position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
```

Gives me an error because StatBin requires a continuous x variable. Any quick fix ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives you the answer: `! StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?`

So instead of `stat_bin()` use `stat_count()`

And for further reference here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- cars |> 
  mutate( discrete_var = factor(speed))

ggplot(data = d, 
       aes(x = discrete_var)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
  stat_count(binwidth = 1, 
             geom = 'text', 
             color = 'white', 
             aes(label = ..count..),
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]